# Minimum length in regular expression

Tags: regex, go

I am well aware that to indicate a minimum length for a regular expression one should use this quantifier, if a min of say 4 characters is wanted `{4,}`

I am trying to compile a regex in `go` that will allow

- a min of 4 chars in **total**, including the hyphen
- only letters digits and hyphens
- last character should **not** be a hyphen

So it was suggested that I use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

which seems to do the job.

Now, given that I want to enforce a min of 4 chars, I modified it a bit as follows:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$
```

However this does not seem to do the work given that the pattern below

```
eee0-lll
```

does **not** [match](https://regex101.com/r/NpgPP9/3) (according to my requirements it should).

One of the constraints I am faced with is that `go` does not allow for lookaround assertions.

Comment: Besides the accepted answer, consider the pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`. The reason `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$` fails is that the `{4,}` applies only to the character-class expression immediately to its left: `eee0-lll` has the first part, up through the `-`, match the first character class, but then there are only 3 characters remaining when the expression requires 4. So instead, we can ask to match 3 or more characters from the set that *does* include `-`, and then exactly one character from the set that *excludes* `-`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{4,}\b$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3oa8ae/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{4,}` - four or more ASCII letters, digits or hyphens
  -`\b` - a word boundary that requires a word char (letter, digit or `_`) to appear immediately to the left of the current position because the next pattern requires...
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming the `\b` for the word boundary is now what it prevents it from ending by a `-` ?

Comment: @pkaramol Yes, I added the details to the answer.